# Displaying camera preview using DirectX Texture2D causes oscillation on Windows Phone 8

Tags: c#, windows-phone-8, thread-safety, texture2d, sharpdx

I am currently writing a small app which shows the preview from the phone camera using a SharpDX sprite batch. For those who have an nokia developer account, the code is mainly from [this article](http://developer.nokia.com/Community/Wiki/Creating_a_Lens_application_that_uses_HLSL_effects_for_filters).

**Problem**

Occasionally, it seems like previous frames are drawn to the screeb (the "video" jumps back and forth), for the fracture of a second, which looks like oscillation/flicker.

I thought of a threading problem (since the PreviewFrameAvailable event handler is called by a different thread than the method which is responsible for rendering), but inserting a lock statement into both methods makes the code too slow (the frame rate drops below 15 frames/sec).

Does anyone have an idea how to resolve this issue or how to accoplish thread synchronization in this case without loosing too much performance?

**Code**

First, all resources are created, whereas device is a valid instance of GraphicsDevice:

```
spriteBatch = new SpriteBatch(device);
photoDevice = await PhotoCaptureDevice.OpenAsync(CameraSensorLocation.Back, captureSize);
photoDevice.FocusRegion = null;

width = (int)photoDevice.PreviewResolution.Width;
height = (int)photoDevice.PreviewResolution.Height;

previewData = new int[width * height];

cameraTexture = Texture2D.New(device, width, height, PixelFormat.B8G8R8A8.UNorm);

photoDevice.PreviewFrameAvailable += photoDevice_PreviewFrameAvailable;
```

Then, whenever the preview frame changes, I set the data to the texture:

```
void photoDevice_PreviewFrameAvailable(ICameraCaptureDevice sender, object args)
{
    sender.GetPreviewBufferArgb(previewData);
    cameraTexture.SetData(previewData);
}
```

Finally, the Texture is drawn using a SpriteBatch whereas the parameters backBufferCenter, textureCenter, textureScaling and Math.Pi / 2 are used to center and adjust the texture in landscape orientation:

```
spriteBatch.Begin();

spriteBatch.Draw(cameraTexture, backBufferCenter, null, Color.White, (float)Math.PI / 2, textureCenter, textureScaling, SpriteEffects.None, 1.0f);

spriteBatch.End();
```

The render method is called by the SharpDX game class, which basically uses the  IDrawingSurfaceBackgroundContentProvider interface, which is [called by the DrawingSurfaceBackgroundGrid](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windowsphone/develop/system.windows.controls.drawingsurfacebackgroundgrid.setbackgroundcontentprovider) component of the Windows Phone 8 runtime.

**Solution**

Additional to Olydis solution (see below), I also had to set Game.IsFixedTimeStep to false, due to a SharpDX bug (see this [issue on GitHub](https://github.com/sharpdx/SharpDX/issues/160) for details).

Furthermore, it is **not** safe to call `sender.GetPreviewBufferArgb(previewData)` inside the handler for PreviewFrameAvailable, due to cross thread access. See the corresponding thread in the [windows phone developer community](http://social.msdn.microsoft.com/Forums/wpapps/en-US/3ed7136d-1acf-44a6-be4a-2c19ebafce48/photocapturedevicegetpreviewbufferargb-returns-old-frames-on-lumia-920).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

**My Guess**

As you guessed, I'm also pretty sure this may be due to threading. I suspect that, for example, the relatively lengthy `SetData` call may be intercepted by the `Draw` call, leading to unexpected output.

**Solution**

The following solution does not use synchronization, but instead moves "critical" parts (access to textures) to the same context.

Also, let's allocate two `int[]` instead of one, which we will use in an alternating fashion.

**Code Fragments**

```
void photoDevice_PreviewFrameAvailable(ICameraCaptureDevice sender, object args)
{
    sender.GetPreviewBufferArgb(previewData2);
    // swap buffers
    var previewDataTemp = previewData1;
    previewData1 = previewData2;
    previewData2 = previewDataTemp;
}
```

Then add this to your `Draw` call (or equal context):

```
cameraTexture.SetData(previewData1);
```

**Conclusion**

This should practically prevent your problem since only "fully updated" textures are drawn and there is no concurrenct access to them. The use of two `int[]` reduces the risk of having `SetData` and `GetPreviewBufferArgb` access the same array concurrently - however, it **does not eliminate** the risk (but no idea if concurrent access to the `int[]` can result in weird behaviour in the first place).